# Replace XML content using Regular Expressions in .NET

Tags: .net, xml, regex

I am trying to work on a regular expression to replace XML content in C# with no success.

Here is the sample code with XML example.

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write(ReplaceValue("<test val='123'><this>something</this></test>", "ANY_XML_BLOB", @"<test[^>]*>\s*(?'value'[^</test]*)"));
    }

    static string ReplaceValue(string request, string newFieldValue, string pat)
    {
        string value = String.Empty;
        Regex conditionRex = new Regex(pat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
        Match match = conditionRex.Match(request);
        if(match.Success)
        {
           value = match.Groups["value"].Value;
           return request.Replace(value, newFieldValue);
        }
        return request;
    }
}
```

Expected output is "this" tag and all sub-contents be replaced by the word ANY_XML_BLOB.

Any help fixing this would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a massive duplicate question, and the answer is, you can't use a regex on XML because XML is not a "regular language". Use LINQ to XML instead.

Comment: I believe that your "can't" is more on philosophical basis. LINQ is out of question for me. Sadly, its REGEX or Die!

Comment: What about [plain old DOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx)?

Comment: Actually, "can't" is more on a mathematical / Computer Science basis, not philosophy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using a proper XML parser for trying to do what you want to do. Using a regex is just asking for trouble. Something in the System.Xml namespace would suit you.  You might even give [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) a try.

PsuedoCode:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("<test val='123'><this>something</this></test>");

XmlNodeList testelelist = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("test");
XmlNode testele = testelelist.Item(0);
testele.InnerText = "ANY_XML_BLOB";
```

Answer (score 2):

While I would recommend following the XML parsing route, you COULD try this:

```
string output = Regex.Replace(input, "<this>.*?</this>", "ANY_XML_BLOB");
```

Comment: This works, but sadly the sample is code is what I have to use to replace the XML content. Hence, I have been using 'value' in the REGEX to replace it later, after the match.